# Retrieving SwissProt from ExPASy server - error

Tags: biopython

I've just started learning my way around Biopython and I'm trying to use ExPASy to retrieve SwissProt records, just like described in page 180 of the Biopython tutorial (http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.pdf), but also in a relevant ROSALIND exercise (http://rosalind.info/problems/dbpr/ -  click to expand the "Programming shortcut" section).

The code I'm using is basically the same as in the ROSALIND exercise:

```
from Bio import ExPASy
from Bio import SwissProt
handle = ExPASy.get_sprot_raw('Q5SLP9')
record = SwissProt.read(handle)
```

However, the SwissProt.read function gives the following error messages (I've trimmed some of the filepaths):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "code.py", line 4, in <module>
    record = SwissProt.read(handle)   File "lib\site-packages\Bio\SwissProt\__init__.py", line 151, in read
    record = _read(handle)   File "lib\site-packages\Bio\SwissProt\__init__.py", line 255, in _read
    _read_ft(record, line)   File "lib\site-packages\Bio\SwissProt\__init__.py", line 594, in _read_ft
    assert not from_res and not to_res, line AssertionError:                 /note="Single-stranded DNA-binding protein"
```

I found this has been reported in GitHub (https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/2417), so I'm not the first one who gets this, but I don't really find any updated version of the package or any way to fix the issue. Maybe it's because I'm very new to using packages. Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Please update your BioPython to version 1.77. The issue has been fixed with pull request [2484](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/pull/2484).

[image]